# Fatal error: Call to undefined function empty()

Tags: php

Any idea why I'm getting this strange error?  "Fatal error: Call to undefined function  empty()"

```
function newpart($name,$country,$bday_day,$bday_month,$bday_year,$gender,$pass1,$pass2,$email,$option1,$secondOption1,$secondOptionLevel1){ 


        $this->name = $name;
        $this->country = $country;
        $this->bday_day = $bday_day;
        $this->bday_month = $bday_month;
        $this->bday_year = $bday_year;
        $this->gender = $gender;
        $this->pass1 = $pass1;
        $this->pass2 = $pass2;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->option1 = $option1;
        $this->secondOption1 = $secondOption1;
        $this->secondOptionLevel1 = $secondOptionLevel1;


        if( empty($this->name) || empty($this->pass1) ){
            $this->errorCount++;
        }



    }
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? Also, this looks like it's a method in a class? Does it work if you do $name instead of $this->name?

Comment: I found some references of that error when trying to use empty as a variable function, like in `$foo = 'empty'; $isEmpty = $foo('something');`. Are you sure the error is caused by the code you pasted? It might be somewhere else.

Comment: Had the same issue with variable functions. From docs:
`Variable functions won't work with language constructs such as echo, print, unset(), isset(), empty(), include, require and the like. Utilize wrapper functions to make use of any of these constructs as variable functions.`

Answer (score 9):

I had the same fatal error...

before the word "empty" I did press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> instead of <kbd>space</kbd> in my editor. There was a fake white space.

Comment: Thats the kind of features I like having on my keyboard. You know, keeps you guessing everytime. Huge props to the guy that once came up with this idea.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think is you are using a version of php older than php 3.  Though I cannot imagine you are on a server running on php3.  Empty() came around in php 3.

Comment: It came about in PHP3. Also, please use comments for questions.

Comment: This page says that it is for php 4, 5: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php  I meant to do a comment instead of an answer, but it may actually be THE answer, so I didn't vote to delete it.

Comment: The current manual does *not* document the version history. For reference: http://www.php.net/manual/php3.php#changed_behaviour And no, that's not THE answer.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I didn't know php3 wasn't included in the same page. I corrected my answer, and how do you know that isn't what the problem is for Jake?

Comment: Well, objects didn't exist prior PHP3 as well.

Answer (score -3):

If the variable isn't set you can get this error. Always when you are using the `empty()`, also use the `isset()`. I guess it will solve it for you.

Comment: No, `empty` does not require the variable to be set.

Comment: Awkward, I have the problem often that it says: `variable undefined, can't run function or something` And the exact same problem I had like Jake was solved by using the isset(). Perhaps there was an error in my code anyway :p. So I was hoping it would work in his situation as well :) Tnx for your answer though @bfavaretto

Comment: -1 Empty is not a function, it's a language construct. When you use empty without isset you get an *notice* that the variable/property/array-index is not set - nothing about the "function not working" empty works fine on variables that are not set (because they are equivalent to NULL).